# What happens to Objective C method with NULL argument?

Tags: objective-c, null

I am new to iOS programming and try to learn some of the basics and core concepts. I know that if we call a method on a NULL object, it does not give any error but it's just that the method won't get called. But what if I have a valid object and I am calling a method on it which takes an argument and that argument is null at the time of its calling. What would happen in that case?

e.g.

```
[self callMethod1:methodArgument];  //methodArgument is null at this time

-(void) callMethod1:(NSString *)methodArgument
{
  //Do Stuff here
}
```

Also, what would happen in the same situation if we are using C/C++ ?

Any answers/ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks
Vik

Comment: If only there were some way you could type that code into your computer, compile it, and see for yourself what happens...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing special about this case, it will just call the method with `nil`/`0` as the argument.
In C++ the behaviour is the same: if you pass a null pointer, the method gets a null pointer as the argument.

Passing `nil` (which is just the name commonly used for null pointers to Objectice-C objects) is meaningful, consider e.g.:

```
[someClass setDelegate:nil]; // unregister delegate
```

Remember that you are passing pointers, not instances.

Comment: thanks for the answer Georg, and what about in case of C/C++? would it give Segmentation fault in that case?

Comment: @Vik: No, you are just passing pointer arguments (i.e. some adress) and `0` is a valid value. You only shouldn't dereference it (e.g. `ptr->someMethod()`, `*ptr`, `ptr[10]`, etc.).

Comment: @Vik - Also note that **[nil someMethod];** is a valid operation and does not raise any exception.